# Responsive table issue when html and body displayed as table

Tags: css

I'm in the middle of finishing off a responsive table for a website I'm building. The problem is that because of the html and body elements being displayed as table (due to being part of a sticky footer solution), the width of the tables containing div is not respecting the 100% width, when scaled down below 745px. Removing the display table from the html and body elements isn't an option due to the sticky footer. I would love to hear if anyone in the community has come across this issue and more importantly managed to find a solution/workaround?

See the link below to a pen with the table in question:

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/garethconnop/pen/XJjMgx)

HTML:

```
<div id="opening-hours">
    <div class="opening-inner">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Monday</th>
                            <th>Tuesday</th>
                            <th>Wednesday</th>
                            <th>Thursday</th>
                            <th>Friday</th>
                            <th>Saturday</th>
                            <th>Sunday</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                            <td><span>Open gym</span><br>07.00-10.00</td>
                            <td><span>PT</span><br>07.00-18.30</td>
                            <td><span>Open gym</span><br>07.00-10.00</td>
                            <td><span>PT</span><br>07.00-18.00</td>
                            <td><span>Open Gym</span><br>07.00-10.00</td>
                            <td><span>Open Gym</span><br>10.00-12.00</td>
                            <td class="closed"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                            <td><span>PT</span><br>10.00-17.00</td>
                            <td><span>Circuits</span><br>18.30-19.30</td>
                            <td><span>PT</span><br>10.00-16.30</td>
                            <td><span>Circuits</span><br>18.00-19.00</td>
                            <td><span>PT</span><br>10.00-18.00</td>
                            <td class="closed"></td>
                            <td class="closed"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                            <td><span>Open gym</span><br>17.00-20.30</td>
                            <td><span>Open gym</span><br>19.30-20.30</td>
                            <td><span>Open gym</span><br>17.30-20.30</td>
                            <td><span>Open gym</span><br>19.00-20.30</td>
                            <td class="closed"></td>
                            <td class="closed"></td>
                            <td class="closed"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the full code and working example see the [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/garethconnop/pen/XJjMgx)

Comment: It looks like the table isn't shrinking further because the contents of the table won't let it get smaller.  Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Tables keep expanding based on their content, even if you give it a fixed width. I'm not sure if there's a solution for this, I would strongly suggest you to use another sticky footer technique.